# C++ Break a loop from another function

Tags: c++, qt

I'm developing a video recording software but I am stuck on an issue.
I want to stop the recording when the button Stop is clicked but nothing happens when I click it...

Here is my core (simplified):
MySoftware.hpp:

```
bool b_Stop = false;
```

MySoftware.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow() : QWidget() {
    qpb_StartCapture = new QPushButton("Start Capture", this);
    QObject::connect(qpb_StartCapture, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(startCapture()));

    qpb_StopCapture = new QPushButton("Stop Capture", this);
    QObject::connect(qpb_StopCapture, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(stopCapture()));
}

void MainWindow::startCapture() {
        b_Stop = false;

        // CAMERAS INITIALIZATION

        while (!b_Stop) {
            for (int i = 0; i < v_cp_Cameras.size(); i++) {
                // IMAGE CAPTURE
            }
        }

        // IMAGES PROCESSING
}

void MainWindow::stopCapture() {
    b_Stop = true;
}
```

Comment: I'm gonna take a wild guess, and say `startCapture` is called from your app's event loop. And so it blocks any event processing...

Comment: Doesn't matter how. Qt is handling the event of a push on `qpb_StartCapture ` by calling `startCapture`. It can't handle another even until it finished handling the current one. And your handler is blocking it.

Comment: Do you think I should put the startCapture() on another thread to prevent the app's event handling from blocking?

Comment: @StoryTeller and because it's Qt there's no delete; but there's news!! This way you can spend hours trying to work out if there's going to be a memory leak.   :)  Yeah - my turn for a rash

Comment: Not all of it. Just the loop that checks `b_Stop` (which you better make atomic if you start spawning threads).

Comment: Don't forget you'll need a way to stop the thread - they don't just magically terminate when you try to close your app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I see it is that `startCapture` is probably called from your event loop. This blocks any other events from being processed. Try putting your loop into a separate thread and see if that works.

Comment: I imagine the great eye does indeed see all. You may be a servant of Morgoth, but have an upvote anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You're having the image capture inside of a for loop that doesn't check whether or not the stop button is activated. You're checking the while loop, which probably never starts over. put `if (b_stop) {break;}` inside the for loop and it might work.